# Deploy my mongodb instance on oracle cloud

Tags: mongodb-atlas, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have my mongodb instance running on MongoAtlas,
I have to host my database to oracle cloud,
Is there a way i can host my mongoDb on Oracle cloud.

i looked into bitnami , but its only giving option to host mongodb on Aws, Google, dnot see oracle there

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is asking for recommendation on cloud hosting option instead of programming.

Answer (score 0):

currently OCI does not have hosted/managed MongoDB offering but you can deploy it on the pure IaaS either via containers or VMs. You can get both of those from Bitnami and deploy them on the OCI IaaS.

What is your use case for MongoDB? If you are looking into hosted/managed DBon OCI , did you check out Autonoumous DB?